# How can I connect the Bot Framework Emulator to a bot running on another machine inside my network without ngrok

Tags: botframework

I would like users inside my network to be able to connect the Bot Framework Emulator to a bot running on another machine inside my network.  This is possible with ngrok, but it seems like ngrok should not be required since all of the machines are on the same LAN.

It appears that older versions of the emulator had a setting for "Emulator Url" which looks like it might have been useful for this, but that setting is not present in the current version (3.5).

Is this possible?

Comment: We pulled this feature from an early version of the emulator in order to reevaluate how to best represent it in the app. In its first incarnation, it was more confusing than useful. If you could lodge an issue over at the emulator's GitHub repo, it would help us prioritize this feature:  https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator

Comment: Done, thanks!  https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/107